# Unobstrusive validation data-val attribute change to ignore or not

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-validation

I created a form to change some value to my current user profile
My main form contains multiple controls.
If I do not fill Old AND new password, I don't want the unobstrusive validation to switch field to error state.

The folowing code works once.

I mean, if both fields are empty, they are ignored.
Next time, the code pass in //#2 if I fill one, it still be ignored

```
$.fn.MyProfile_Save = function () {
///<summary>
///MyProfile save button click handle
///</summary>
var form = $("#frmMyProfile");
///Check witch fields must be validated
var PwdOld = $("#pwdOldPassword");
var PwdNew = $("#pwdNewPassword");
if ((PwdOld.val() + PwdNew.val()) == '') {
    //#1
    PwdOld.attr("data-val", "false");
    PwdNew.attr("data-val", "false");
} else {
    //#2
    PwdOld.attr("data-val", "true");
    PwdNew.attr("data-val", "true");
}
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
if (form.valid()) {
    alert("form valid");
} else {
    alert("form NOT valid");
}
```

}

Can you help me to understad why it works only one time ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution :

```
$.fn.MyProfile_Save = function () {
///<summary>
///MyProfile save button click handle
///</summary>
var form = $("#frmMyProfile");
///Check witch fields must be validated
var PwdOld = $("#pwdOldPassword");
var PwdNew = $("#pwdNewPassword");
if ((PwdOld.val() + PwdNew.val()) == '') {
    PwdOld.addClass("ignore");
    PwdNew.addClass("ignore");
} else {
    PwdOld.removeClass("ignore");
    PwdNew.removeClass("ignore");
}
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
var settings = $.data(form[0], 'validator').settings;
settings.ignore = ".ignore"; 
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
if (form.valid()) {
    alert("form valid");
} else {
    alert("form NOT valid");
}
```

}